# count records and display with Special field

Tags: sql, count

```
ID  case    date    time
----------------------------------
101  A      2001    1
101  A      2002    2
102  A      2001    1
103  B      2001    1
101  B      2003    1
101  A      2004    3
102  C      2006    1
101  B      2007    2
103  C      2007    1
```

**what is sql query for**

for ID, count every case and show just date for time 1.

sample:
Output for ID=101 :

```
ID  case    date    qty
-------------------------------------
101  A      2001    3
101  B      2003    2
```

Please guide me about this.

Comment: why do u write 2001 for ID 101. why not other dates. because 101 with case 'A' is having multiple date values

Comment: Because date of 2001 has time value 1.

Comment: What did you tried as query?

Answer (score 0):

Below query is based on your sample output. 
You can try this

```
SELECT id, case, date, count(time) as qty
FROM table
WHERE id = 101
GROUP BY id, case, date
```

Comment: qty is not a table field

Comment: yes as per the above query the sum of time will be displayed as "qty"
qty is an alias for sum(time)

Comment: I guess now this query should work. If yes then please upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help you Sas. I found the answer.

```
select id, case, min(time), count(*) as qty
from table
group by id, case
having id=101
```

Comment: use where = 101 
where clause to restrict rows. and having clause to restrict groups

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT id, case, count(*) as qty, max(case when time = 1 then date end) as date
FROM table
WHERE id = 101
GROUP BY id, case
```